# What is the right code to hide fields in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-parsing, show-hide

How to hide the other fields if the option in spinner is not selected using XML and XSLT?

E.g I have a spinner with three options

```
Option 1: Form 1
Option 2: Form 2
Option 3: Others
```

If the user choose option 1, all fields under option 1 will display, while the fields under option 2 is hide (vise versa)

Is this correct?

```
 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Form/Field">   
    <xsl:variable name="Category" select="Spinner"/>
        <select id="Form">
            <xsl:for-each select="$Item">
                <xsl: value="{.}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="type"/>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```

XML:

```
<Field name="Category" type="Spinner" label="Please choose">
    <Item code="CashPickupForm" label="Cash Pickup"/>
    <Item code="HomeVisitForm" label="Home Visit"/>
    <Item code="OtherForm" label="Others"/>
</Field>
```

Here's some XML of Form 1

```
<Form name="CashPickup"
  type="TextView"
  label="Cash Pick-up Form">

<Field name="ContractNumber" type="TextView" label="Contract number" value=""/>
<Field name="ClientName" type="TextView" label="Client Name" value=""/>
<Field type="Delimiter"/>
```

XSL:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Form"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Form">
<xsl:element name="Form">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='ns2') and not(name()='')]"/>
  <xsl:call-template  name="Arrange"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Arrange">

<xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='ContractNumber']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='ClientName']"/>
<Field type="Delimiter"/>
```

XML Form 2:

```
<Form name="HomeVisitForm"
  type="TextView"
  label="Home Visit Form">

<Field name="ContractNumber" type="TextView" label="Application number" value=""/>
<Field name="TypeCheck" type="TextView" label="Type of check" value=""/>
<Field type="Delimiter"/>
```

XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="Form"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Form">
<xsl:element name="Form">
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="type">
    <xsl:value-of select="@type"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="label">
    <xsl:value-of select="@label"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='ns2') and not(name()='')]"/>
  <xsl:call-template  name="Arrange"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Arrange">

<xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='ContractNumber']"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='TypeCheck']"/>
<Field type="Delimiter"/>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? If so, please, delete the question since it is a little erratic in its current state. If not, leave a comment and we can try to add substantial information to your question that will be required to answer it.

Comment: Not yet. I'm still finding solution for this @MarcusRickert

Comment: OK. So these are my initial questions/suggestions: when supplying XML files make sure you declare as *Source XML* (your input) or *Target XML* (desired output). You should only have one XSLT (currently you have two snippets). Your XML files have unbalanced tags. Could you double-check? To make the XSLT react to the current selection you will have to store this selection somwhere in a variable. What would be your preferred way of passing this selection to the XSLT? A parameter?

Comment: @MarcusRickert Yes by a parameter as possible

Comment: What about my other questions/comments?

Comment: I already edit the XML. Regarding in desired output, I don't know how to figure it out with XML, but my desired output is there's a question and there are three options: form1, form2 and others (can use a spinner for this) If the user choose form1, all fields under form1 will be display while the other fields that's not belong in form1 will be hide

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62924/discussion-between-marcus-rickert-and-user014019).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you pass a parameter called `FormType` to your XSLT containing either the value `1` or `2` (as a start and possibly other values later on) you could enhance your XSLT in the following way:

```
...
<xsl:parameter name="FormType"/>
...
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="Form"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Form">
  <Form name="{@name}" 
        type="{@type}"
        label="{@label}">
    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*[not(name()='ns2') and not(name()='')]"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="Arrange"/>
  </Form>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="Arrange">

  <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='ContractNumber']"/>

  <xsl:if test="$FormType = '1'">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='ClientName']"/>
    <!-- you may put more fields here if applicable-->
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:if test="$FormType = '2'">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Field[@name='TypeCheck']"/>
  </xsl:if>
  ...
  <!-- you may put more if blocks here if applicable -->
  ...
  <Field type="Delimiter"/>
  ...
</xsl:template>
```

Notes:

- I have simplified your `<xsl:element>` tags using simple HTML tags.
- This is just an example for one field. You may have to add more `<xsl:if>` tags if required.
- If the order is right you may put more than one field into one `<xsl:if>` block.